# Create new folder using URL for name - Java

Tags: java

I am trying to create an empty folder with the name http://www.example.com/, but for some reason I can't. I tried:

```
    File dir = new File("http://www.example.com/");
    dir.mkdir();
```

but nothing happends. Why?

Comment: did you try to create a folder with this name manually ??in windows you can't

Comment: Ok thanks, that's the problem

Comment: read this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File("C:\\DirectoryData");
if (!file.exists()) {
    if (file.mkdir()) {
        System.out.println("Directory created!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to create directory");
    }
}

File files = new File("C:\\Directory2\\Subdir\\Subdir");
if (files.exists()) {
    if (files.mkdirs()) {
        System.out.println("directories created!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to create directories!");
    }
}
```